# Laravel esta petición debería devolver un STATUS CODE 201 no 200

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-7, laravel-8

Tengo esta función que sirve para enviar un password mediante mailgun, esta función comprueba si se puede hacer el envio según una lógica de negocio (máximo de 3 veces al dia) y si es así hace el envio.

La función funciona correctamente lo que me esta dando "por saco" es la respuesta de esta petición ja que quiero usar el statuscode que devuelve ya sea un 200 o 201 (faltan más estados por definir pero para el ejemplo con estos dos suficiente)

```
    /**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return string
 */
public static function sendNewPassword(Request $request): string
{

    $email = $request->get('email');

    $cansend = EmailService::canSendEmail($email);

    if ($cansend) {
        return response($result,200);
    }
    else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Excedido límite diario'], 201);
    }       
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo en la respuesta según postman me devuelve un 200 pero debería devolver un 201.
Si os fijáis en la captura en la parte izquierda pone "HTTP/1.0 201 Created" en cambio en la parte derecha un "200 OK"

Esto lo quiero hacer asi porque luego desde JS al hacer la petición quiero usar la respuesta para hacer una cosa u otra, tipo esto

```
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('api.mail.users.newpassword') }}",
        dataType:"json",
        data: {
            email : email,
            password : password,
            _token: '{{csrf_token()}}',
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Email enviado correctamente')
            },
            201: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Excedido el límite diario')
            },
            401: function() {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Usuario no autorizado')
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: No veo la relación que quieres establecer entre el mensaje *excedido el límite diario* con el código de estado `http` 201. Si no se puede realizar la operación, entonces el código de estado `http` no debería ser 2xx sino 4xx. Por ejemplo [429 - Too many requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429). Te sugiero repases la [lista de códigos de estado `http`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). Saludos

Comment: Si tienes razón en vez de un 201 devolveré un 429, pero como ejemplo ya me servía.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado el error...el problema estaba en la definición de la función tenia puesto que retornaba un *string*, he eliminado esto y funciona.

```
public static function sendNewPassword(Request $request): string
```